# Pandoc Markdown to PDF doesn't show images

Tags: pdf, html, pandoc, markdown

I used knitR to convert R Markdown files to Markdown, and I'm trying to use Pandoc to convert them into HTML/PDF.

Markdown to HTML includes all my images in the output, using

```
pandoc test.md -o test.html
```

However, Markdown to PDF doesn't include any of my images in the output, using

```
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
```

(there are other options because I am doing syntax highlighting that will show up in printed output, but no combination of them seem to include images in the PDF output).

In the actual Markdown file, images are referenced as:

```
<img src="images/image_to_include.png" title="Default title" alt="alt text" style="display: block; margin: auto;" />
```

where image_to_include.png is in the images subdirectory. The alternate text is not displaying either.

I would like to know how to get images to appear in the PDF output of Pandoc, but I am also curious to know why HTML seems to allow it and PDF doesn't.

My OS is Yosemite and I have installed MacTeX.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pandoc includes raw HTML only if the output format is HTML-like. From the [web-site](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-html):

> The raw HTML is passed through unchanged in HTML, S5, Slidy, Slideous, DZSlides, EPUB, Markdown, and Textile output, and suppressed in other formats.

In order to get images to work for both, HTML and PDF writer, you have to use [pandoc's own format](http://pandoc.org/README.html#images):

```
 ![la lune](lalune.jpg "Voyage to the moon")
```

Comment: Not so nice solution when we want to use a bit more complex html blocks, e.g., to have the image next to text and further resize the image. So, this use case is just not supported by pandoc ?

Comment: Well, this is still off topic, but you still can do whatever you want in HTML blocks. You can also use raw LaTeX. But if you want to generate multiple output formats you have to stick to pandoc's own ways. If you read the manual, you can find out about sizing options etc. And you can always write your own filters to do fancy stuff.

Maybe you should ask a new question here if your problem is about generating LaTeX output with PDF . . .